# Pyinstaller ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am making a viewer using Qgis, Pyqt5, and I plan to make it into exe and implement it. It runs well on code, and until the day before it was obtained, exe was normally generated and executed. However, the build itself has not been built with exe since yesterday. The original py file and the spec file without adding anything are built, but the spec file with hidden import and additional settings results in ValueError: source code string channel container null bytes. What's the reason?

Development Environment : Window10, anaconda3 Virtual Environments

Python : 3.7.7

not use ui files

sepc file and code = UTF-8

[this image pyinstaller error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rmXA.png)

[this my spec file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a7yd.png)

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the spec file is actually in UTF-8 encoding like it claims, and not something like UCS2 (in which case, about half of the bytes actually are null bytes)?

Comment: I checked that the spec file was utf-8, saved as UTF-8, and saved again.